# C++ Parameter passing for class constructor (reference)

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing

What is the difference between:

```
classConstructor(const std::string theName);
```

and

```
classConstructor(const std::string& theName);
```

Since constructor just initialises a member, is there any difference between these 2 statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the '&' character befor your variable name it means that this variable will be the SAME as the one passed in parameter. When i say the same, i mean, in memory. It's a bit like a dereferenced pointer.

It's just an optimization. Instead of creating a new variable in memory just for your constructor here, you'll use the same memory space. Here with a simple string, the difference is negligible, but imagine with a huge vector of objects (for example).

Sometimes it's usefull to, to use it as a pointer in C. You can modify your variable in another function without passing a pointer.

Finally, this is called a "Reference" ;)

Hope you're helped ;)

Comment: What if I initially passed in a string without storing it to a variable location? Then this two statement has no difference?

Comment: You mean like that for example : 
`int   function_test(const std::string & str)
{do some stuff}
`
And you call it liek that : `function_test("String test")`

If yeah, it works, cause even if you don't set it in a variable, your string will be created in the memory somewhere. In this case it's just a simple optimisation ;). But it still works ;)